# How to form this RAW sql statement with Query Builder Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Maybe someone here can help me to form this RAW SQL Statement with Query Builder from Laravel

**

```
DB:: select(DB:: raw("select min(heartrate) as hr, max(rotation) as rot, max(calories) as cal 
                                          from trainingsdatas, trainings 
                                          where trainings.user_id = $id 
                                          and trainingsdatas.training_id= trainings.id "));
```

**

This is one try:

```
DB::table('trainingsdatas')
->join('trainings','trainings.id','=','trainingsdatas.training_id')
->min('heartrate as hr')
->max('rotation as rot')
->max('calories as cal')
->where('trainings.user_id','=', $id)
->get();
```

**

There is always an error.. The Syntax seems not correct.

Comment: what do you mean by "form"?

Comment: how do i get the correct query with Query Builder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using select

```
DB::table('trainingsdatas')
->join('trainings','trainings.id','=','trainingsdatas.training_id')
->selectRaw('min(heartrate) as hr, max(rotation) as rot, max(calories) as cal')
->where('trainings.user_id','=', $id)
->get();
```

Comment: I get this error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'min(heartrate)' in 'field list' (SQL: select `min(heartrate)` as `hr, max(rotation)` from `trainingsdatas` inner join `trainings` on `trainings`.`id` = `trainingsdatas`.`training_id` where `trainings`.`user_id` = 1)

Comment: if this doesn't work you need to prefix your columns with the corresponding table name `min(trainings.heartrate)`

Comment: the updated version worked but there is a RAW statement inside the query.

But thank for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $trainings = Trainings::query()->where('user_id', $id)
->join('trainingsdatas', 'trainings.id', '=', 'trainingsdatas.training_id')
->select(DB::raw('MAX(rotation) as rot'), DB::raw('MIN(heartrate) as hr'), DB::raw('MAX(calories) as cal'))
```